# id passed to MVC controller always mapped as 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have a database full of vehicle data. My API can be used to return a list of all vehicles, but not a single vehicle. The controller code is listed below along with my mvc mapping from `Startup.Configure`

Why is it that whatever parameter I use (say '27' for the id) it is always mapped as 0?

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult GetVehicle(int vehicleId_)
{
    try{
        var specificVehicle = _vehicleRepository.GetVehicleById(vehicleId_);

        if (specificVehicle == null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(specificVehicle));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to retrieve specific vehicle : {ex}");
        return BadRequest("An Error Ocurred retrieving a specific vehicle. 
         Check Logs.");
     }
}
```

From *Startup.Configure*

```
app.UseMvc( config =>{
config.MapRoute(
    name    : "Default",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
);
```

Comment: could you try [HttpGet)]
public IActionResult GetVehicle(int vehicleId_)

Comment: the name in the route template needs to match the name of the parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it that whatever parameter I use (say '27' for the id) it is always mapped as 0?

The name of the parameter in the route template needs to match the name of the parameter in the action.

You currently have differing names `{id:int}` in the route template verses `int vehicleId_` in the action.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult GetVehicle(int id) {
    try{
        var specificVehicle = _vehicleRepository.GetVehicleById(id);

        if (specificVehicle == null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(specificVehicle));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to retrieve specific vehicle : {ex}");
        return BadRequest("An Error Ocurred retrieving a specific vehicle. 
         Check Logs.");
     }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)